# Simple guide to use bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an app that requires the use of Bluetooth to send data like 4-5 numbers and 2-3 texts between devices but i am new to java and the guide from google developers page is a little difficult for me to understand.

In order to make it easier for anyone whiling to help me i will write down in steps what i have done so far.

**1**. I have asked for permissions in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**2**. I got the default adapter in my activity:

```
 final BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

**3**. I created a button that when clicked the device scans for other devices:

```
bt_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //first checks if bluettoth is enabled
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                //if not it enables it 
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
             // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        }
    });
```

**4**. When a device is found, get the device information:

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
            // object and its info from the Intent.
            BluetoothDevice device = 
 intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
        }
    }
};
```

**5**. On destroy unregister the ACTION_FOUND receiver:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Don't forget to unregister the *ACTION_FOUND* receiver.
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

**6**. I have created a second button that when clicked it enables discoverability (which must be clicked first from device *A* in order for *scan* button in device *B*,  finds the device *A*):

```
bt_enable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new 
        Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);      
        discoverableIntent.putExtra( BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);

        }
});
```

**Questions :**

**A.** In step **3** what *REQUEST_ENABLE_BT* is for?

**B.** Is this all i need to establish a connection without any problems between two devices?

**C.** If i want to connect more than two devices, is there anything else i must add?

Comment: if you are starting an activity to get a result then you need to handle the onActivityResult. REQUEST_ENABLE_BT is used in that method to understand which request is returning a result (in case you have more)

Comment: I really recommend RXAndroidBLE, a popular Android library that takes care of a lot of the boilerplating involved with Bluetooth on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q. What is `REQUEST_ENABLE_BT` for?**

Let me try to comment the code

```
// If bluetooth is not switched on
if ( ! mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled() ) {
    // Create a system request to enable bluetooth
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent( BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE );
    // Queue the request to pops the bluetooth dialogue
    startActivityForResult( enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT );
}
// Standby for device found, Bluetooth may still be disabled at this point
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter( BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND );
registerReceiver( mReceiver, filter );
// Now that we are done, bluetooth dialogue will popup
// When it's done Android calls our onActivityResult
// (because we queued it with startActivityForResult).
```

---

**Q. Is this all I need to establish a connection?**

I think there are two more more steps you need to do:

A. Find the device, between step 3 and 4.

Just enabling Bluetooth does not mean it'll automatically scan nearby devices, because scanning cost battery and degrades existing connections.
But with `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission your app can start and stop the scan.
You can also get previously paired device without scan.

- Start Scan: [BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery())
   This will call `ACTION_FOUND` for each device found, which fit your code.
- List of paired devices: [BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#getBondedDevices()) 
   Previously paired Bluetooths can be found in this `Set` without scanning or `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`, and can be connected directly. 
   Whether the device is actually online is unknown until successful or failure, though.

B. Establish the data connection, between 4 and 5.

A device connection is like connecting a network cable.
The computers are physically connected with IP, but your programs still need to open sockets for actual data transfer.

- Connection: [BluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)) Creates a socket from which data can be go through `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.
- Don't forget to stop the scan: [BluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#cancelDiscovery())

> You seems to want to make an M2M messaging app, so I've skipped Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).

---

**Q. If I want to connect more than two devices, is that all?**

As far as "multiple connection" part is concerned, no, you don't need to do anything special to connect to multiple devices at the same time.

The "management" is arguably the hard part, though.
For example you'd normally want to keep a list of the devices, and have a UI that let user selectively disconnect a device, all of which must respond to unexpected disconnections or switching off bluetooth (by user, by another app, or by the system such as low-power mode).

Depends on what you actually want to do with the bluetooth devices, you may need code to remember each one's state too.
Again with error handling.

So, do expect the final code will be a bit more developed.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer **Question A**

**A. In step 3 what REQUEST_ENABLE_BT is for?**

```
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
```

*REQUEST_ENABLE_BT* is simply an integer value which identifies your request. When you receive the result Intent, the callback `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` provides the same request code to you. In this way you can handle results from other activites

Suppose you have **Activity A** from where you have requested to enable bluetooth

```
Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

When device's bluetooth gets enable, a method `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` will get invoked on **Activity A**. This method `onActivityResult()` is a callback method. This method will pass back the request code to the calling activity (**Activity A**) as soon as bluetooth gets enable. You have to override this method in your **Activity A** to handle results.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
        Log.d("BLUETOOTH", "Successfully enabled");

}
```